# Joining two indentic select queries in order to get different rows in different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

A select-query of mine always returns a table with one column, but multiple rows.
I now want to modify the query to append a column with exactly the same data in it to the table, and then LIMIT the first row to 1 and the second to 1,2
(I want to get the "Top X" of some result, each in a different column.)

My current, not working query, looks like this:

```
SELECT tag1, tag2 FROM
(
    (SELECT tag1...) AS t1
    JOIN
    (SELECT tag2...) AS t2
);
```

Unfortunately, the joined column contains the same value in each row:

```
Top1    Top2
1234    1234
4321    1234
6543    1234
8765    1234
```

Whereas the result should be this:

```
Top1    Top2
1234    1234
4321    4321
6543    6543
8765    8765
```

So that I can select the first value in the Top1 column and the second in the Top2 column. The final result should therefore be:

```
Top1    Top2
1234    4321
```

How can I achieve this, and why isn't my query working?

Comment: Why don't you simply do `SELECT tag1, tag1 AS tag2...`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Because I have no idea how I should get the corresponding top1/top2 value, since limit applies to the whole table and not only to one column. As I said in my post, the end-result should only contain one value per column.

Comment: Unless I'm reading this wrong, you want both columns to have the exact same values. in this case a simple select of the same column with different aliases will do the trick. if I'm wrong, you should change the expected result you posted.

Comment: @ZoharPeled In an intermediate step, I want both columns to have exactly the same value. But look at my final result: There the "Top1" column only contains the first row, whereas the "Top2" column only contains the second row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would you want to show for Top2 when Top1 is the last value?

Try this: (edited to get tag3 as well)

```
SELECT tag1, tag2, tag3 FROM
(
(SELECT tag1...) AS t1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT tag2...) AS t2
ON(t1.tag1 < t2.tag2)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT tag3...) AS t3
ON(t2.tag2 < t3.tag3)
) LIMIT(1);
```

This should give you the next value of tag1 in tag2 column. of course, you will not go through the step where both columns with equal values.

Note that the more left joins you add, the slower the execution time will be.

Comment: Wow, this works! Thanks! And how would I modify this code in order to get, for example, the Top3? (Top1 = First Value, Top2 = Second Value, Top3 = Third Value) - Since the statement in ON is a boolean I can't really imagine how to do it...

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm pretty sure it works! I have another question tho... My select-queries are a bit longer and I can't seem to get it to work... Would you be so kind and look over it for me =(?